# C++ Blowfish Hashing Implementation

Tags: c++, blowfish

A number of scripting languages (Python/PHP/etc...) include functionality (sometimes through extensions) that allows you to use Blowfish as a one way hash on passwords.  I'm trying to find a similar implementation for C++ but everything I've come across is an encryption/decryption solution.

Can somebody recommend a library for C++ that provides the same functionality?

Comment: Maybe you should start over. Blowfish is a symmetric cipher; how do you imagine it relates to hashing?

Comment: @Kerrek Please take the entire post into account...  see the first answer for some info on use in scripting languages as a hashing algo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Comment: @KerrekSB, it is very common to use a symmetric cipher as part of a cryptographic hash: [OpenBSD allows using blowfish for password hashing](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=crypt&sektion=3&arch=&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD+Current), [`pam_unix` provides a blowfish option](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/pam_unix.8.html). `crypt(3)` uses a modified DES as part of the password hashing mechanism. (It was modified so existing off-the-shelf DES crackers couldn't be used to brute-force passwords. Seems quaint in retrospect.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a java version at [jbcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/). There's a paper on bcrypt at [openbsd.org](http://www.openbsd.org/papers/bcrypt-paper.pdf) and [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163389.aspx). You can find the source for bcrypt at http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/crypt/ and more info at http://www.openwall.com/crypt/